# horizontal scrollbar does not show

Tags: c#, winforms

I have listView in tabControll. listView.Scrollable = true and vertical scrollbar appears normally.

After opening the window, horizontal scrollbar does not show. When I minimize the window the scrollbar appears and after maximalization it stays there. I cant see the reason, why the scrollbar is not there when I start app for the first time.

On the bottom there is no component that could be over the scrollbar.

Comment: What is 'frame'? Where screenshots and/or code?

Comment: thanks for advices and edit, it is my first post here. I cannot post code or screens now, because i dont have notebook with me at the moment, i just wanted to ask, because i couldnt google it or find it here.

Comment: The simplest suggestion I can offer is putting the ListView into a Panel with enabled horizontal scrolling.

Comment: you can try manually setting (in the code) the `Width` to see if that sets it off. There's an old bug here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92a49d7c-1043-4cbd-a5c6-c61c1958e5e3/how-to-get-scrollbar-on-listview?forum=wpf that had a similar problem with the vertical bar in a gridview.